# *This and Operator Overloading in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, this

The code below is a working function within the Polynomial class. The function overloads the minus operator to allow the subtraction of two polynomial equations through objects. The functions, setArray and getArray, are involved because the user inputs an array of doubles to represent the coefficients.

I understand how operator overload works in C++ without *this, however I am confused about the way overloading is done with *this in the code snippet.

What does it mean to set an object (Polynomial equation) equal to a dereferenced pointer?

```
Polynomial Polynomial::operator-(int rval2) {
 Polynomial equation = *this;
 equation.setArray(equation.getArray() - rval2);
 return equation;
}
```

According to my understanding, pointers point to a an address and can be repeatedly reassigned a new address. Dereferencing the pointer allows the access of the value at the current address.

Comment: There is no address reassignment going on.  Look up `copy constructor`.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment from *this invokes a copy constructor, that object is then modifed and a copy of that local object is returned.